# Next.js/React application with pm2: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, pm2

I'm new to next.js and react.  I have created a simple application and would like to serve it using pm2 and Apache.

When I run `npm run dev` in the folder of the next project, the server starts and I can see my application on port 3000 of localhost.

However, when pm2 attempts to run the application (I have set it to run on server boot), I get the following error in the pm2 logs:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:468:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:21)
```

`node --version` is `v16.19.0`
`npm --version` is `8.19.3`

Can someone help me to fix this issue?  I don't understand why it is happening at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Without providing more information and context, it will be difficult to diagnose exactly what is going wrong. If you want good answers, you need to list out a more comprehensive list of things you've tried and information about how you are setting up nextjs with pm2.

But right now, the character is your best clue. "<" hints at the problem likely being that html markup is being loaded somewhere it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.  I had neglected to build the project with `npm run build`.  Once I'd done that, pm2 worked as desired.